# How do you initialize a non-nullable property as a this pointer in a kotlin data class?

Tags: kotlin

Given a Kotlin data class, how do you initialize a non-nullable property as a pointer to self? I.e something like the following pseudocode.

```
data class Node(var other: Node = this)
```

Currently I have a solution that introduces temporary properties

```
data class Node(val _other: Node? = null) {
    var other: Node = _other ?: this
}
```

Comment: Why use `val _other`? Remove the `val` keyword

Comment: @Zoe That gives the error "data class primary constructor must have only property val/var parameters"

Comment: So don't use a data class.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, however, for my purposes I need the functionality of a data class like equals and copy and I would prefer not to have make the property nullable and/or implementing the functionality manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thank you for your feedback, however, for my purposes I need the functionality of a data class like equals and copy and I would prefer not to have make the property nullable and/or implementing the functionality manually.

You'd still have to: `equals` and `copy` will care only about `_other` and ignore `other` (just as they would ignore all other properties defined in the body of the class). That `other` is a `var` just makes it worse: reassigning it will have no effect on data class functionality.

But you can come closer:

```
data class Node(private var _other: Node? = null) {
    var other: Node
        get() = _other ?: this
        set(value) {
            _other = if (value != this) value else null
        }
}
```

The only problem remaining is that [`component1()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) will return `_other`. In this case you have a single property so it shouldn't matter.

EDIT: after thinking a bit more,

```
data class Node(private var _other: Node? = null) {
    init {
        this._other = _other ?: this
    }

    var other: Node
        get() = _other!! // safe
        set(value) {
            _other = value
        }
}
```

seems to effectively be what you want. You can see difference here:

```
val node1 = Node()
val node2 = node1.copy(node1)
println(node1 == node2)
```

prints `false` with the first solution, `true` with the second one (as it should if `this` was the default parameter).

Comment: Thank you for the improved solution and the clarification regarding how the automatic copy/equals work. I assume from your answer that my prefered solution is not possible to express but your workaround at least solves most problems. In the actual code I use more than one property so component1() returning _other is regretable but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You cannot access `this` before it is constructed. But that's just how the default constructor parameter would work.

```
Cannot access '<this>' before superclass constructor has been called
```

Comment: It isn't possible in this specific way, but my answer shows how to achieve the same result.